# quick question on printing results in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently trying to print the results of list using a for loop in python, but I want the last number to print a space, then a newline. for ex.

```
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]

for num in hourly_temperature:
    print(num, '-> ', end= '')
```

I'm getting `90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95 ->`   but i want `90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95`

I've tried using `len` and `range` with `if` `else` statemets, but i didt really work.

Comment: Did you mean `'-> '.join(hourly_temperature)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
' -> '.join(str(element) for element in hourly_temperature)
```

Comment: Thanks that did trick, seems ```join()```  is the opposite of ```split()```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a for loop you can loop over every element except for the last one, and then print the last one manually, like this:

```
for num in hourly_temperature[:-1]:
    print(num, '->', end='')
print(num[-1])
```

It might be simpeler to use join though, for example:

```
strs = [str(x) for x in hourly_temperature] #convert values to str
print('->'.join(strs))
```

This converts your list to string with a '->' between every two elements.

Comment: To use join a string is expected and not integer!

Comment: Oops, fixed it.